# Password Encryption IN ASP.Net mvc4 web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on ASP.NET MVC4, web API and I tried to write Password encryption code 
In Register controller I wrote this code

```
 namespace PasswordHash.Controllers
{
    public class RegisterController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        //POST api/values
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(user user)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "value");
            var db = new passwordhashEntities();
            var checkExitUser = (from c in db.users where c.UserName == user.UserName select c).Count();
            if (checkExitUser == 0)
            {
                var newUser = new user()
                {
                    Email = user.Email,
                    UserName = user.UserName,
                    Password = PasswordHashHelper.CreateHash(user.Password),
                    PostCode = user.PostCode,
                    SlowHash = user.SlowHash


                };
                db.users.Add(newUser);
                db.SaveChanges();
                response.Content = new StringContent("Resgister successfully ", Encoding.Unicode);
            }
            else
                response.Content = new StringContent(user.UserName + "is exit", Encoding.Unicode);

            return response;
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

the run time error apear in this line : var checkExitUser = (from c in db.users where c.UserName == user.UserName select c).Count();
the error is : An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

I think I need to install some tools or programs, but I do not know what is this tool? because I tried to apply other encryption tutorials and also It did not work with me with same error.

Comment: Catch the exception so you can actually read the error message.

Comment: This generic exception usually contains an innerexception that explain better what's happening. See the Exception.InnerException,Message

Comment: how can I find Exception.InnerException?

Comment: Debug your code, put a breakpoint on the line (F9) and run. When you hit the line the debugger stops execution F11 to step forward and when the exception raises look at its details

Comment: Is your class really named `user` and not `User`?  Perhaps you need to be using an uppercase "U"?

Comment: If you remove password encryption function, will it solve your problem?
I think you got your error not because of password encryption.